# Mysql prepared SELECT statement not echoing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, select

Basically I am setting up a mysql prepared select statement and it uses a GET to pull the id from the url the problem I am having is that the category and description variable is not echoing.

I have used a non prepared statement and it works perfectly fine. I have tried inputting variables into the bind result.

```
$catid=intval($_GET['cid']);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "Select id,CategoryName,Description,PostingDate,UpdationDate from  tblcategory where Is_Active=1 and id='$catid'");
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $category,$description,$catid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($category,$description,$catid);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $category;
echo $description
```

The expected results of this code is to pull the catid from the url and select all of the column information and then to be able to echo the description and category variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your output, you need to bind columns from the result set *in the order they are specified in the query*. In your case you have `$catid` in the wrong place. This should work:

```
$stmt->bind_result($catid, $category, $description);
```

Note that you are missing bindings for `PostingDate` and `UpdationDate`, and you may want to add them too e.g.

```
$stmt->bind_result($catid, $category, $description, $postdate, $updatedate);
```

You also have an issue with your input, you are binding parameters that don't exist in the query. Since your query has only one input, you should replace that with a placeholder and bind to that:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "Select id,CategoryName,Description,PostingDate,UpdationDate from  tblcategory where Is_Active=1 and id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $catid);
```